# Getting the height of a relative div container

Tags: css, height, css-position

I have a `DIV` that contains lots of child `DIV` elements. The container `DIV` has the `position` attribute set to `relative`, and all the child elements have their `position` attributes set to `absolute`. Each of those has positional data set using `top` and `left`. I wish to add a footer after the container, but it's height is being registered as 0px. Is there a way to set it so that it's height will expand to encompass all the child elements (via CSS only, no javascript)?

Comment: Absolute positioning is usually discouraged for positioning the entire page. Could you share some code? One way is to set a fixed height, but that's out of the question for you.

Comment: You can't give a minimum height to the container?

Comment: Sadly not, there is a variable number of items within it, giving a potential minimum height of 216px, and a potential maximum height of 2200px.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Specs says:

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block. [1]

So, CSS can't expand the height of the container to encompass all the absolutely positioned  DIV's

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning